# Zoom with UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, zooming

Why am I not able to zoom with UIScrollView? I set min / max zoom factor in storyboard. What else do I need?

- I have already added subviews to my scrollview
- set content size
- content is bigger then the the scrollview itself, so it is space for zooming

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Need to implement `viewForZoomingInScrollView` UIScrollViewDelegate method.

```
func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {

    return self.scrollViewContent
}
```

It should return a subview inside scrollview. I put a subview that has exact the same size as scrollview contextSize.